# How would I implement google's new reCaptcha in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement the new Google recaptcha in my Rails 4 app but I'm unable to get the widget to display in Haml. Basically what I'm trying to do is to make this code

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>`

into somehting like this:

```
%div{class: 'g-recaptcha' data-sitekey: 'your site key'}
```

The way how I try to write it above gives me an error on the data-sitekey part.

I also tried to write it like this:

```
%div{class: 'g-recaptcha' 'data-sitekey' => 'your site key'}
```

and still no luck. Has anyone attempted to do this? Apparently there is not too many stackoverflow questions or online resources dealing with this. But if someone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it?

*Also, what is the data-sitekey considered? It's not a class or an id. What is it? Maybe I have the formatting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most concise equivalent haml:

```
.g-recaptcha{data: {sitekey: 'your site key'}}
```

Your second example would also be equivalent, but you're missing a comma:

```
%div{class: 'g-recaptcha', 'data-sitekey' => 'your site key'}
```

`data-sitekey` is a html5 [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

[html2haml](http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/) can convert HTML to haml.

Comment: Holy hell thanks so much. How did I not hear about html2haml before?